# Polynomial Regression not giving what I want

Tags: python, regression

I'm using the following code to make a polynomial fit to a set of data. It works fine for simple exponentially growing plots but this set of data gives strange results and negative values when it should be positive exponential decay. Attached image is a fit to the data which is useless.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('ML_mobility_6.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

# Fitting Ploynomial regression to the dataset
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4) #degree of polynomial
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly, y)
lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X))
# Visulize Linear Regression Results

# Visualize Polynomial Regression Results
X_grid = np.arange(min(X),max(X), 10)
X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid),1))

#original data
plt.scatter(X, y, color="red")
#xgrid is the values you want to predict in place of test data
plt.scatter(X_grid,lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X_grid)),color="blue")
```

The data I am using is:

```
30.04   1.97
30.43   1.92
30.84   1.86
31.26   1.81
31.7    1.76
32.15   1.72
32.62   1.67
33.11   1.62
33.61   1.57
34.13   1.52
34.67   1.47
35.23   1.43
35.8    1.38
36.4    1.33
37.02   1.29
37.66   1.24
38.32   1.2
39      1.16
41.99   0.985
45.43   0.835
49.37   0.7
53.89   0.583
57.72   0.504
61.97   0.433
66.68   0.37
71.91   0.315
77.7    0.267
84.13   0.225
91.26   0.189
99.17   0.157
114.3   0.116
128.5   0.0887
144.7   0.0675
163.4   0.0507
184.8   0.0375
209.4   0.0274
237.6   0.0197
270     0.014
307.2   0.00994
338.7   0.0075
373.6   0.00574
412.4   0.00433
455.3   0.00325
503 0.00243
555.9   0.00182
614.5   0.00136
679.5   0.00102
751.6   0.000749
831.7   0.000557
920.4   0.000413
```

Many Thanks

[image]

Comment: You mention that your data represents exponential decay, so why do you use a degree-4 polynomial in your regression? If a polynomial isn't appropriate to your data, then polynomial regression will provide useless fits.

Comment: But it works for exponential growth. Should I log it and use a linear fit then?

Comment: Since the curve is fitted to the lowest absolute error squared, and graphically that is the vertical distance from the curve to the data squared, the data on the left-hand side of the graph is dominating the fit causing a poor fit on the right-hand side of the graph. Either data transformation or non-linearly fitting a different equation should help.

Comment: I found an excellent fit to the Hocket-Sherby exponential equation "Y = b - (b-a) * exp(-1.0 * c * pow(X, d))" with an R-squared of  0.99998 and a Root Mean Squared (RMSE) value of 0.003 using coefficients of a = -2.1795456318146151E-03, b = 1.2081474375841406E+01, c = 2.9672804672395307E+02, and d = -2.1805735526178731E+00

Comment: Many Thanks for that. I will have a look into that equation. Do you think part of a Gaussian could also work?

Comment: Do you know how you would go about implementing this equation into the regression model above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask in the comments how to implement the fitted equation I suggested, and here is the code using my pyeq3 fitting library (pip3 install pyeq3). As the equation is very sensitive to initial starting parameters, the fitting library uses the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to determine initial parameter estimates to get a good fit.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyeq3


##########################################################
# text data section
dataString = '''
30.04   1.97
30.43   1.92
30.84   1.86
31.26   1.81
31.7    1.76
32.15   1.72
32.62   1.67
33.11   1.62
33.61   1.57
34.13   1.52
34.67   1.47
35.23   1.43
35.8    1.38
36.4    1.33
37.02   1.29
37.66   1.24
38.32   1.2
39      1.16
41.99   0.985
45.43   0.835
49.37   0.7
53.89   0.583
57.72   0.504
61.97   0.433
66.68   0.37
71.91   0.315
77.7    0.267
84.13   0.225
91.26   0.189
99.17   0.157
114.3   0.116
128.5   0.0887
144.7   0.0675
163.4   0.0507
184.8   0.0375
209.4   0.0274
237.6   0.0197
270     0.014
307.2   0.00994
338.7   0.0075
373.6   0.00574
412.4   0.00433
455.3   0.00325
503 0.00243
555.9   0.00182
614.5   0.00136
679.5   0.00102
751.6   0.000749
831.7   0.000557
920.4   0.000413
'''


##########################################################
# pyeq3 fitting section

# this example fits to default lowest sum-of-squared errors
equation = pyeq3.Models_2D.Exponential.Hocket_Sherby('SSQABS')

# note that True is passed here to indicate weighted data, for unweighted pass False
pyeq3.dataConvertorService().ConvertAndSortColumnarASCII(dataString, equation, False)

print("Fitting data...")
equation.Solve()


##########################################################
# text output section for fitted parameter values

print("Equation:", equation.GetDisplayName(), str(equation.GetDimensionality()) + "D")
print("Fitting target of", equation.fittingTargetDictionary[equation.fittingTarget], '=', equation.CalculateAllDataFittingTarget(equation.solvedCoefficients))
print("Fitted Parameters:")
for i in range(len(equation.solvedCoefficients)):
    print("    %s = %-.16E" % (equation.GetCoefficientDesignators()[i], equation.solvedCoefficients[i]))
print()


##########################################################
# calculate absolute, relative, and percent errors from the fit
equation.CalculateModelErrors(equation.solvedCoefficients, equation.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary)


##########################################################
# this section prints information on each individual data point
for i in range(len(equation.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary['DependentData'])):
    print('X:', equation.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary['IndependentData'][0][i],)
    print('Y:', equation.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary['DependentData'][i],)
    print('Model:', equation.modelPredictions[i],)
    print('Abs. Error:', equation.modelAbsoluteError[i],)
    if not equation.dataCache.DependentDataContainsZeroFlag:
        print('Rel. Error:', equation.modelRelativeError[i],)
        print('Percent Error:', equation.modelPercentError[i])
    else:
        print()
print()


##########################################################
# overall fit and parameter statistics output section

equation.CalculateCoefficientAndFitStatistics()

if equation.upperCoefficientBounds or equation.lowerCoefficientBounds:
    print('You entered coefficient bounds. Parameter statistics may')
    print('not be valid for parameter values at or near the bounds.')
    print()

print('Degress of freedom error',  equation.df_e)
print('Degress of freedom regression',  equation.df_r)

if equation.rmse == None:
    print('Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE): n/a')
else:
    print('Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE):',  equation.rmse)

if equation.r2 == None:
    print('R-squared: n/a')
else:
    print('R-squared:',  equation.r2)

if equation.r2adj == None:
    print('R-squared adjusted: n/a')
else:
    print('R-squared adjusted:',  equation.r2adj)

if equation.Fstat == None:
    print('Model F-statistic: n/a')
else:
    print('Model F-statistic:',  equation.Fstat)

if equation.Fpv == None:
    print('Model F-statistic p-value: n/a')
else:
    print('Model F-statistic p-value:',  equation.Fpv)

if equation.ll == None:
    print('Model log-likelihood: n/a')
else:
    print('Model log-likelihood:',  equation.ll)

if equation.aic == None:
    print('Model AIC: n/a')
else:
    print('Model AIC:',  equation.aic)

if equation.bic == None:
    print('Model BIC: n/a')
else:
    print('Model BIC:',  equation.bic)


print()
print("Individual Parameter Statistics:")
for i in range(len(equation.solvedCoefficients)):
    if type(equation.tstat_beta) == type(None):
        tstat = 'n/a'
    else:
        tstat = '%-.5E' %  ( equation.tstat_beta[i])

    if type(equation.pstat_beta) == type(None):
        pstat = 'n/a'
    else:
        pstat = '%-.5E' %  ( equation.pstat_beta[i])

    if type(equation.sd_beta) != type(None):
        print("Coefficient %s = %-.16E, std error: %-.5E" % (equation.GetCoefficientDesignators()[i], equation.solvedCoefficients[i], equation.sd_beta[i]))
    else:
        print("Coefficient %s = %-.16E, std error: n/a" % (equation.GetCoefficientDesignators()[i], equation.solvedCoefficients[i]))
    print("          t-stat: %s, p-stat: %s, 95 percent confidence intervals: [%-.5E, %-.5E]" % (tstat,  pstat, equation.ci[i][0], equation.ci[i][1]))


print()
print("Coefficient Covariance Matrix:")
for i in  equation.cov_beta:
    print(i)


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelScatterGraph(equation, graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)
    y_data = equation.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary['DependentData']
    x_data = equation.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary['IndependentData'][0]

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(x_data, y_data,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data))

    tempcache = equation.dataCache # store the data cache
    equation.dataCache = pyeq3.dataCache()
    equation.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary['IndependentData'] = numpy.array([xModel, xModel])
    equation.dataCache.FindOrCreateAllDataCache(equation)
    yModel = equation.CalculateModelPredictions(equation.solvedCoefficients, equation.dataCache.allDataCacheDictionary)
    equation.dataCache = tempcache # restore the original data cache

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_title(equation.GetDisplayName()) # add a title
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot


graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelScatterGraph(equation, graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Wow. That is actually incredible. Thank-you so much for taking the time to do that, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I mostly just copied-and-pasted your data into an existing pyeq3 example - uhh, I mean, er, ahh, I stayed up for days working on that!

Comment: Haha, amazing. So presumably you could apply this to a number of different lines with similar but slightly different curves.

Comment: That is actually one of the main purposes for the library. To see it in action for both curve and surface fitting, check out zunzun.com - it has hundreds of equations with source code links at the bottom of every page, and has a "function finder" for equation search.